# Pecl install uploadprogress fails silently

Tags: ubuntu, php, pecl

When I run the command pecl install uploadprogress, outputs the following:

```
downloading uploadprogress-1.0.1.tgz ...
Starting to download uploadprogress-1.0.1.tgz (8,536 bytes)
.....done: 8,536 bytes
```

Why does it not install pecl or extract it?  It seems that I can extract and install it manually, but I'd like to be able to install it using pecl.  I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Debian/Ubuntu the tool you should probably be using [dh-make-php](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/dh-make-php) to build pecl extensions for the packaged version of PHP.

I just built it on a spare system using these commands.

```
cd /usr/src
pecl download uploadprogress
dh-make-pecl --only 5 uploadprogress-1.0.1.tgz 
cd php-uploadprogress-1.0.1/
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot
cd ..
dpkg -i php5-uploadprogress_1.0.1-1_i386.deb
```

If you don't already have `build-essential`, `php5-dev`, and `apache2-prefork-dev` installed you will also need to add those packages.